# creating an 'insert into' function using variables for schema names

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a function to insert data into a table. The query I'm using won't be changing except for the schema names need to be variables. For instance, one of my schema names is bscu.members and then there's 35 others which are very similar (wea.members, pcu.members.. etc etc..). I couldn't find any help on how to create a function in Postgresql using variables.

this is what i came up with so far but it isn't working

```
create or replace function attsummary(varchar)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
 BEGIN
insert into dwh.attribution_summary
select
m.source,
m.name,
m.partner_id,
d.ucic,
b.acct_type_desc as acct_desc,
a.begin_mo_balance as opening_balance,
c.date,
h.campaignname,
g.description as banner_desc,
f.create_time::timestamp as time_served,
'd' as dep_or_loan,
'h' as home_or_nonhome  
   from
$1.fact_deposits a
join $1.dim_acct_type b on a.acct_type_id = b.acct_type_id
join $1.dim_date c on a.date_id = c.date_id
join $1.dim_members d on a.ucic = d.ucic
join ad_delivery.sgmt_adic e on d.adic::varchar = e.adic
join ad_delivery.sgmt_user_tracker f on e.cookie_id = f.id
join ad_delivery.ox_banners g on g.bannerid = f.banner_id
join ad_delivery.ox_campaigns h on h.campaignid = f.campaign_id
join ad_delivery.sgmt_kli_adic i on e.adic = i.adic
join dwh.sgmt_clients m on m.partner_id = i.sgmt_partner_id
   where
  i.kli=8616208
   and m.partner_id::integer != 909909
```

and then my select statement comes after.. I am using $1 for my variable where the schema name usually goes.

Comment: You will need to dynamically construct your insert statement, See [Executing dynamic statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be dynamically generated

```
create or replace function attsummary
(schema text)
returns void as
$body$
begin
execute format('
insert into dwh.attribution_summary
select
    m.source,
    m.name,
    m.partner_id,
    d.ucic,
    b.acct_type_desc as acct_desc,
    a.begin_mo_balance as opening_balance,
    c.date,
    h.campaignname,
    g.description as banner_desc,
    f.create_time::timestamp as time_served,
    ''d'' as dep_or_loan,
    ''h'' as home_or_nonhome  
from
%1$s.fact_deposits a
join %1$s.dim_acct_type b on a.acct_type_id = b.acct_type_id
join %1$s.dim_date c on a.date_id = c.date_id
join %1$s.dim_members d on a.ucic = d.ucic
join ad_delivery.sgmt_adic e on d.adic::varchar = e.adic
join ad_delivery.sgmt_user_tracker f on e.cookie_id = f.id
join ad_delivery.ox_banners g on g.bannerid = f.banner_id
join ad_delivery.ox_campaigns h on h.campaignid = f.campaign_id
join ad_delivery.sgmt_kli_adic i on e.adic = i.adic
join dwh.sgmt_clients m on m.partner_id = i.sgmt_partner_id
where
    i.kli=8616208
    and m.partner_id::integer != 909909
', $1);
end;
$body$
language plpgsql volatile
;
```

Comment: why the %1$s instead of $1 for the schema name?

Comment: The %1$s is the [format function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) parameter

Comment: whenever i try to run this query:
        select attsummary('bmcu');   i get this error: ERROR: ERROR: function format(unknown, text) does not exist

 Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types.
You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL

Comment: @precose The format function only exists in 9.1+. If using an earlier version check dbenhur answer

Answer (score 1):

@Clodoaldo gave you a working answer, but note that the format() function he used isn't available prior to Pg 9.1.  If you need this to work on older Pg instances you can use string expressions to build your dynamic query.  Example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA a;
CREATE SCHEMA b;

CREATE TABLE a.foo ( data text );
CREATE TABLE b.foo ( data text );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_with_schema(schema_name text, data text)
  RETURNS void
AS  $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(schema_name) || '.foo (data) VALUES ($1)'
    USING data;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: this might be a dumb question but where would i put my query at in this code?

Comment: You would include this function definition in the sql you play to set up your schemas and tables.  To use it you issue a sql statement like `SELECT insert_with_schema('<schema_name>', value);`  Of course you need to modify it to match the table name your using in your multiple schemas and accept the values you actually want to insert.  Mine is just an example.